# How to zip and encode-base64 the files in a folder of a SFTP server using Java program

Tags: java, base64, sftp, zip

I am working on some requirement where I need to zip and (base64) encode files which are placed in a folder with in an SFTP server, how can I achieve using the java program, please suggest.

Comment: try writing some code - usually a good first step

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski - Pardon ?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily Java comes with everything you need for ZIP and Base64:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html

For SFTP you'll need to use a third party library like JSch:
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html
Which I have used in the past, it's quite easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

We may not be able to do the Zip and encode in the SFTP server by executing the some java code from another machine.

But if it is local machine we can do the zip and encode like @Andreas Hartmann mentioned.

Thanks for the inputs team.